# Generate random number just once in first entry

Tags: android

I want to generate number in first entry and save and use for anytime.I used `SharedPreference`.
When application started for once(first entry), the code generated a number.but if not first entry, `Random number` didn't save. 
How to generate number in first entry and use it?

CODE:

```
int i;  
TextView tv;

public void onCreate(){

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    if(!prefs.getBoolean("firstTime", false)) {
        Random r=new Random();
        int i=r.nextInt(100);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("firstTime", true);
        editor.commit();
    }

    tv.setText(i+"");//if "first run" set a number if not set "0"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [SharedPreferences.contains](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#contains%28java.lang.String%29) to check if key is already present in `SharedPreferences` before calling `prefs.getBoolean`. if not then store it first time and if present then get value from SharedPreferences :

```
if(prefs.contains("firstTime")){
 // generate random number first time
 // first time store random number 

}else{
  // already present get value from SharedPreferences
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onCreate(){

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    if(!prefs.getBoolean("firstTime", false)) {
        Random r=new Random();
        i=r.nextInt(100);//<-------- don't re declare I
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("firstTime", true);
        editor.commit();
    }

    tv.setText(i+"");//if "first run" set a number if not set "0"
}
```